# Google Maps API not appearing

Tags: javascript, html, css, api, gis

Trying to add a small google maps API to a webpage (with only header) for an assignment. This is the code I have, which doesn't seem to be working. My external css file is also not linking up. Any ideas as to the issue?
Thanks!

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
    <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mapstyle.css">
    </head>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Find A User's Location</title>
                            <script type="text/javascript"             src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
  <style>
   html { height: 100%; }
   body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
   #mapCanvas { 
    width: 90%; 
    height: 90%; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
   }
            
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var map;
  function initialize(){
   var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };
  map = new   google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapCanvas",         mapOptions));
   //var defaultLocation = new google.maps.Latlng(38.8860, -76.9451);
            function getLocation() {
     if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setMarker, error);
    } else {
      alert("Your browser does not support geolocation.");
    }
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function (pos) {
      var lat = pos.coords.latitude, 
          lng = pos.coords.longitude;
      coords = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
      mat.setCenter(currentLocation);
      map.panTo(coords);
    }, error);
  }}
            
            locationError(error)
            
   var defaultLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(38.8860, -76.9451);
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapCanvas"),      mapOptions);
   //google.maps.Map ()
   map.setCenter(defaultLocation);
   //map.setCenter(defaultLocation);
        
        }
        var umd = {lat: 38.8860, lng: -76.9451};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: UMD
        });

        var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
            '<div id="siteNotice">'+
            '</div>'+
            '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">UMD</h1>'+
            '<div id="bodyContent">'+
            '<p><b>College Park</b>Home of the University of Maryland+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>';

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: contentString
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: UMD,
          map: map,
          title: 'UMD'
        });
        marker.addListener('click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
      }
            function locationError(error){
              var content;
                switch (error.code){
                    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                        alert("Geolocation access denied");
                        break;
                        
                    case error.TIMEOUT:
                        alert("Geolocation is not available");
                        break;
                        
                    case error.TIMEOUT:
                        alert("Timeout to get Geolocation");
                        
                    default:
                        alert("Unknown error in Geolocation");
                }

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        //       var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.getDetails({
        
            placeId:         'EioxMDEgRSBNYWluIFN0LCBNYXJzaGFsbHRvd24sIElBIDUwMTU4LCBVU0E'
        }, function(place, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: place.geometry.location
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
                        'lat lng: ' + place.geometry.location + '<br>' +
                        place.formatted_address + '</div>');
                    infowindow.open(map, this);
                });
            }
        });

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            map: map
        });

        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var pos = {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                    lng: position.coords.longitude
                };

                infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
                infoWindow.setContent('Home');
                map.setCenter(pos);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

                    title: 'Your current location',
                    map: map,
                    //  title: 'Your current location'
                });

            }, function() {
                handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
            });
        } else {
            // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
            handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }
            
  window.addEventListener("load", initialize, false);
  //window.onload = initialize;
   
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
       <div id="header">helllo</div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

   </body>
   </html>
   </div>
 </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: anything in the **developer** tools console about a missing API KEY perhaps?

Comment: it was working without the key until i continued editing it

Comment: So you're saying there's no errors in the console

Comment: By the way your code and html are horribly formatted. Makes my eyes bleed trying to read it

Comment: `</body>
   </html>
   </div>
 </body>
  </html>` at the end is interesting

Comment: your `getLocation` function is never called, you call `locationError` inline for no reason, you call `new google.maps.Map` inline - your **developer** tools console *must* be a wall of errors with that code

Comment: `it was working without the key` - go back to where it was working - then try again

Comment: You should try clean coding and with proper fomatting. Its so hard to debug. By the way what was  your result previoulsy? Its just a text saying 'hello' ? I found lots of missing parenthesis within your script making your script not functioning properly.

Comment: I'm new to this.. my result was just text. how can i validate it properly?

Comment: the external CSS isn't even working.